# How can one ComboBox's items be determined by another ComboBox's selected item?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, winforms

Hi I'm Using Visual Studio 2010, and what I want to know is how can I relate two Comboboxes.  I've 2 ComboBoxes: the first is populated with a list of items from the database and I want to create a second ComboBox With a different type of list based on the choice of the first ComboBox.

Example: First Combobox with all the continents and the second ComboBox with all the nations. I want that the nations list of the second ComboBox changes according to the selected continent in the first ComboBox.

In SQL I've two tables: `Continents` and `Nations`.

Comment: are you using `C#` or `VB`? Title says C# but your first sentence says VB.

Comment: Sorry !! my mistake .it's Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the selectedvaluechanged property of the combobox to load launch a sub that fires the query for the second combobox.

You see a use a 'me.initiallyloaded' property in the code below, the combobox has the disadvantage that it also fires when the form is first loaded. Using this boolean prevents that.

```
Private Sub ComboBoxClients_SelectedValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripComboBoxClients.TextChanged
    If (Me.InitiallyLoaded) Then
        LoadData()
    End If
end sub
```

Comment: Its good @real_yggdrasil, but check out the c# tag in his question.

Comment: Sorry, point taken, currently i am in a project that uses both c# and vb.net at the same time, so i'm used to being 'bi-lingual':)

Comment: hehe, @real_yggdrasil . Understandable;)

Comment: Sorry Guys..it's my mistake , its was supposed to be Visual Studio 2010 .

Comment: Thanks guys for helping me out !! @real_yggdrasil you solved my second problem too..

Comment: But i'm having a hard time relating the two combobox , when the first combobox value is changed i want the second combobox to display items depending on the choice made on the 1st combo. hope i did explain myself properly this time.

Comment: @real_yggdrasil , Is there a property like InitallyLoaded in C# because i cant Find it while usng c# , or am i missing a directive or refrences !